# WF8 & C# & SQLite & autoincrement & Fail

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, auto-increment

I try to use the SQLite Library for WP8.

I defined a table:

```
class ShoppingItem
{
  [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Shop {get; set;}
  public bool isActive {get; set;}
}
```

According to http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html a value is assigned to `Id` automatically by sqlite, if no value for `Id` has been given. Right?

So I try to insert new entries by

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(m_DatabasePath)) {
    db.Insert(new ShoppingItem() {
      Name = anItem,
      Shop = aShop,
      isActive = aIsActive,
    });
}
```

When I insert a first item, it gets the ID 0. Well, why not.
When I insert a second item, i get a SQLiteException with the awesome message "Constraint".
So how can I insert a new entry without giving an id?

btw.:
As an alternative solution, I tried to add a null value to id, but this resulted in a compilation error. :(

```
...
db.Insert(new ShoppingItem() {
  Id = null, // <- does not compile
  Name = anItem,
...
```

Comment: Is your ID an AUTOINCREMENT in your table in your database?

Comment: No, but I do not think this is necessary, according to http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ShoppingItem` does not know that the field is autoincrementing, so it assigns a default value of zero.

Use:

```
[SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
public int Id {get; set;}
```

Comment: yeah, it works, thank you.
But I don't understand why I have to add the `AutoIncrement` flag, as the AutoIncrement should be done automatically by SQLite?!
Or is my problem a matter of the SQLite lib for C#?

Comment: The problem is that C# automatically assigned a value.